# Computation with Gaussian measures on Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-measure

What follows is based on the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02093v2, specifically section 1.2 about Gibbs measures.

The setup is the following:

Let $\mu$ be the Gaussian measure on $H^s(\mathbb{T}^2)$ ($s<0$, and $H^s$ are Sobolev spaces defined in the usual sense of Fourier multipliers) defined by
$$
d\mu = \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} \int |u|^2 + |\nabla u|^2 dx \right) du $$

In the paper, Oh and Thomann show that you can compute the covariance operator associated to this measure explicitly ($C = (1 - \Delta)^{-1+s}$), but they then claim that $\mu$ is only a probability measure on $H^s(\mathbb{T}^2)$ when $s < 0$, as "$\mu(L^2(\mathbb{T}^2)) = 0$". How does one go about showing this equality, and why does this show failure of $\mu$ to be a probability measure?

Comment: They are using a lot of jargon. If you have never seen this stuff, don't start from that paper. I remember some good lecture notes of Gigliola Staffilani on Gibbs measures for dispersive PDEs, you might want to run a web search for them.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro It doesn't seem that these lecture notes are still available online, or at least not in the form you mention. Do you have a link or an actual PDF copy of the notes?

Comment: Yes, sorry, here's the link; http://math.mit.edu/~gigliola/Staffilani-trieste.pdf Section 1.5 is relevant to you.